# Find the area bounded by $x+y=3$ and the coordinate axes.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the area bounded by $x+y=3$ and the coordinate axes.

I know how to find the area bounded by 2 curves it's just that I'm confused with "coordinate axes". Is it the same as x=y? or not? please help me understand.

**Edit:** Okay, the coordinate axes are given by $y=0, x=0.$

I tried to solve it. I got 9/2.

Here's my solution:

If $x=0, y=3$ and if $y=0, x=3$.

$$\int_0^3 (3-x)dx = 3x-[(x^2)/2]\Big|_0^3 =[3(3)-(9/2)]-0 =9/2$$

Did I do it right?

Comment: Coordinate axis refer to the y axis ($x=0$) and the x axis ($y=0$).

Comment: Note if you graph the situation you have a triangle with base 3 and perpendicular height 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being asked to find the area of the triangle formed by the lines

- $x+y= 3$,
- the $x$-axis $(y = 0)$,
- and the $y$-axis $(x = 0)$.

To find the bounds of integration, assuming you'll integrate with respect to $x$, your lower bound will be $x=0$. The find the upper bound of integration, you'll need to find where $x+y = 3$ when $y = 0$.

---

EDIT:

Yes, you are correct. The desired integral for computing the area bound by the given lines is $$\int_0^3 (3-x)\,dx = 3x-\frac {x^2}2\Big|_0^3=\left(9-\frac 92\right) -(0) = \frac 92$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct you can solve it the way you did or you could solve it with the simple formula Area = $(1/2)bh$. The x-intercept is $(3,0)$ and the y-intercept is $(0,3)$. This gives you the height and the base of the triangle: height - 3 units, base - 3 units.

Area = $(1/2)*3*3=4.5 units^2$